# C++ Linux TCP sockets fd

Tags: c++, sockets

how do i change the socket id/FD after i use accept() ? lets say i bind() on sockfd 3 and the accepted client is on sockfd 4, how do i change/move that sockfd to 1000?

OS : Ubuntu

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: Dean's got a good question there.  You might have a good reason (probably involving fork()), but it's more likely you're thinking it will achieve something it won't, or confusing the import of fds with port numbers....

Comment: i don't think i'm confusing fds with ports.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Still you didn't specify the OS so I will go with *nix :)

http://linux.die.net/man/2/dup2

Comment: that helps alot, but next - how do i release the resources associated with the original FD without closing the connection - usually close() ?  or  dup2() makes it always automatically?

Comment: here is something very basic of what i did:

    //my acceptsock=accpet();
    if(check is admin ip)
    {
    
    int oldsock=acceptsock;
    //copy from receiving sockfd (accept-lowest free) to custom sockfd
    acceptsock=dup2(oldsock,800+serverconnections);
    //add acceptsock to my fd_set in the thread where admin data
    //is processed
    //release the resources of the accept() sockfd 
    //close - does not not close the connection! perfect!
    close(oldsock);
    }
    else
    {
      //normal client connection
    }
    i can now easily distinguish types of clients :)